# Comparing 2 CSV files with different length and find out additional data

Tags: dataframe, numpy, csv, numpy-slicing

I have two CSV files, both have different numbers of rows and Columns, in File 1, I have the below structure,

| PRODUCT NAME | PRODUCT TYPE | PRODUCT SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Galaxy S6 | Android Phone | IAJ83934830485 |
| Surface Pro | Windows Tablet | IM94545435493 |
| iPhone 13 | iOS Device | IK983459435493 |

File 2 has below structure

| Shipment Day | Price | PRODUCT SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thursday | 70.5 | IAJ83934830485 |
| Friday | 121.3 | IK983459435493 |

What I am trying to achieve is to compare product serial column to find out the Shipment Day and Price from the other dataframe for devices that are in it so the final result is as follows

| PRODUCT NAME | PRODUCT TYPE | PRODUCT SERIAL | Shipment Day | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Galaxy S6 | Android Phone | IAJ83934830485 | Thursday | 70.5 |
| Surface Pro | Windows Tablet | IM94545435493 | N/A | N/A |
| iPhone 13 | iOS Device | IK983459435493 | Friday | 121.3 |

I have tried using Numpy where but results are not accurate. Any suggestions or advise would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas library to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the files into two dataframes.
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# Merge the two dataframes, using _ID column as key
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'PRODUCT-SERIAL')
df3.set_index('PRODUCT-SERIAL', inplace = True)

# Write it to a new CSV file
df3.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

additional reference link: [Merge two CSV files based on a data from the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383305/merge-two-csv-files-based-on-a-data-from-the-first-column)

Comment: This solution needs `how="left"` in the merge, otherwise it drops the products that don't have a serial match in `df2`.